# Angular Service BehaviorSubject displays duplicate data using Async Pipe

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

First, I have a service - `ContractorsService` - with a function `getContractors` that makes a Firebase Firestore call to the `contractors` db using the AngularFire method.

I used pipe to first switchMap the results from a snapshot in order to get the uid for each contractor record, and append the uid property to the rest of the iContractor model, then I filter based on authenticated userId which contractors to display in the template.

I finish the pipe with another map to service function `isContractorRecordComplete` that accepts a parameter of `contractorId`, and returns `Observable<number>` and that number is appended to the contractor object in the map.

The map finishes by adding the latest `iContractor` object to the BehaviorSubject.

That BehaviorSubject is made public and is used in the template as an `Iterable` with an async pipe.

**I am getting inconsistent behavior between:**

- **initially loading the page gives me duplicate objects in the BehaviorSubject to display in the template**
- **after editing a Contractor and coming back to the Contractor listing page, the page only displays the one Contractor edited, and no other Contractors**
- **other pages that reference the `contractors` db using the AngularFire Firestore snapshot only display the Contractor object edited and no other Contractors**

See latest code below:

contractors.service.ts

```
getContractors(noIndicator: boolean) {       
   this.userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ms_user'))?.uid;
   let _contractorsArray: iContractor[] = [];  

   this.afs.collection('contractors').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      switchMap(actions => actions.map(a => {                    
         const data = a.payload.doc.data() as iContractor;
         const id = a.payload.doc.id;                                                                                
         return { id, ...data };
      })),
      filter(contractor => contractor.userId === this.userId),
      map((c: iContractor) => {
         if(noIndicator == false){
            this.isContractorRecordComplete(c.id).subscribe(completionPercent => {
               let contractor: iContractor = {...c, completionPercent};
               _contractorsArray.push(contractor);
               this.contractorCollection.next(_contractorsArray);
            });
         }

         if(noIndicator == true){
            _contractorsArray.push(c);
            this.contractorCollection.next(_contractorsArray);
         }                                
      })
   )
}

isContractorRecordComplete(uid: string): Observable<number> {
   return this.afs.doc<iContractor>(`/contractors/${uid}`).valueChanges().pipe(
      map(_contractor => {    
         if(_contractor){
            let THEcontractor = new Contractor;
            let populatedFieldSum = 0;
                    
            for (const [requiredKey, data] of Object.entries(THEcontractor.fieldsForCompletion)) {
               Object.keys(_contractor).forEach(cKey => {
                  if(cKey == requiredKey){
                     if(_contractor[cKey] !== undefined && _contractor[cKey] !== ''){
                        populatedFieldSum = populatedFieldSum + data.weight;
                     }

                     if(requiredKey == 'logo' && _contractor[cKey].indexOf('placeholder_contractor.jpg') > -1){
                        populatedFieldSum -= 5;
                     }
                  }
               })
            }                

            return populatedFieldSum;
         } else {
            return 0;
         }
      })
   );
}
```

contractors.component.html

```
<section class="grid-container">
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="500px" *ngIf="this.contractorService.contractorCollection$ | async">
    <ng-template ngFor let-contractor [ngForOf]="this.contractorService.contractorCollection$ | async">
      <mat-grid-tile
         *ngIf="!contractor.archived"
         [colspan]="1"
         [rowspan]="1"                    
      >            
         <contractor-card [contractorData]="contractor"></contractor-card>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </ng-template>        
  </mat-grid-list>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two async pipes subscribing to the same observable. That's two separate subscriptions, and I think that's causing your duplicates. Try aliasing your first async pipe and using the alias on the second. That way you subscribe once.

```html
<section class="grid-container">
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="500px" *ngIf="(this.contractorService.contractorCollection$ | async) as contractors">
    <ng-template ngFor let-contractor [ngForOf]="contractors">
      <mat-grid-tile
         *ngIf="!contractor.archived"
         [colspan]="1"
         [rowspan]="1">            
         <contractor-card [contractorData]="contractor"></contractor-card>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </ng-template>        
  </mat-grid-list>
</section>
```